# Choosing clusters that are closest to the mean of all data?

Tags: clustering

So the problem is like this;

Assume there are 5 bridges spread out in a city. We counted the number of cyclists passing through each of them on random days. Now we want to install sensors on the bridges to estimate the average traffic in the city, however, we can only choose 4 bridges out of the 5.

I believe we have to eliminate the bridge that changes the mean by the least amount. However, I couldn't think of a good way to formulate this. Do I just remove them one by one and observe how much does the mean change, or is there a better method to achieve this (like some kind of a reverse PCA that instead of removing features removes classes)?

Comment: Doesn't it make sense that removing the bridge closest to the mean would, other things being equal, change the mean by the least amount? Now the fly in the ointment is the "other things being equal" and they likely aren't. For example, if the bridge closest to the mean has most of the data, that might not be the case that removing it is such a good idea. Are you sure you want a least change in mean as a criterion? Maybe a better idea is to remove the bridge with the least traffic. In any case, if there are only five bridges, removing each to see which produces the least mean change is simple.

Comment: I am not sure of that criterion, hence I asked if there is a better way to achieve this.
I settled with removing the bridge that showed the least correlation with the total traffic.